# Warhammer 40,000: Inquisitor Martyr tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[So I've created a new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inquisitor-martyr) and was a little unsure about the tag that should be used.

I settled with `inquisitor-martyr` as that seemed the most logical tag to use. However the Dawn of War 2 tag does not include the Warhammer 40k moniker, but the Dawn of War tag does.

- [warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war)
- [dawn-of-war-soulstorm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-war-soulstorm)
- [dawn-of-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-war-2)
- [warhammer-40k-carnage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-carnage)

When a game is part of a franchise like this, should the franchise be included in the tag? Should these tags all be brought into a consistent naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Whenever possible, use the full, official name of the game

The full name of the game as [presented on their website](https://neocoregames.com/en/games/warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr) is *Warhammer 40,000: Inquisitor - Martyr*. Therefore, we would ideally tag the game as [warhammer-40000-inquisitor-martyr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40000-inquisitor-martyr).

However, you've noticed that this hasn't been consistently followed, largely because of the limit on the number of characters on a tag name. The limit used to be 25 characters, which caused problems for games like *Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War - Soulstorm*. The character limit is now 35 characters, and these games should have been retagged.

That said, [warhammer-40000-dawn-of-war-soulstorm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40000-dawn-of-war-soulstorm) is 37 characters, which is over our limit. Given that there is the common abbreviation of `40k`, that is the obvious choice. For consistency of games of the franchise, I think that all of these games should be prefixed with `warhammer-40k`.

- [dawn-of-war-soulstorm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-war-soulstorm) → [warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-soulstorm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-soulstorm) (35 characters)
- [dawn-of-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-war-2) → [warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-2) (27 characters)

This would mean that the name for this game would be [warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr), with variants as tag synonyms.

Comment: I have updated the question I created with the new tag, but I lack the privileges to make the synonym.